# Demand with regression analysis in R program

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, forecasting, industrial

I have a data frame which contains just 12 elements.which are;

`32072,12062,47063,23237,32993,48605, 28670, 34622, 38168, 29813, 42659, 36072` I want to make some predictions with this elements. I am a new R user. I searched a lot but I didn't find how to forecast with regression analyssis. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The basic idea is model <- lm(y ~ x, df) but you need a data frame with two elements, a independent variable (x) and dependent (y)

Comment: Now I have variable (x) and (y) . I know how to make  regression line . Are they similar I don't know but I wrote .  `data_x<-c(32072,12062,47063,23237,32993,48605, 28670, 34622, 38168, 29813, 42659, 36072)
data_y<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
plot (data_x, data_y,main ="scatterplot of x and y")
mod<-lm(data_y~ data_x)
abline(mod, col=2, lwd=3)
summary (mod)
`  I don't know am I right with write it. Then I think I need to  define df . But what am I suppose to right indsde the df . Thanks your help.